# Prevent form submit from triggering buttons

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a few textboxes in it and a few buttons. I have a couple custom form elements that I am working on. One, in particular, is a textbox that will search a database onEnterClicked. This works just fine, but I also have a button that will run code onClick. Both of these appear to be linked to submitting the form.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" id="autofill">
    ...
    <button id="upload">
```

When I run this jQuery code:

```
$("input#autofill").keyUp(function(e){
    //Do stuff
});

$("button#upload").click(function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

Pressing enter in the autofill textbox will show the test alert, but will not do any of the `//do stuff` code.

How can I prevent this from happening?

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("#autofill").keyup(function(e){
    
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    alert("Enter pressed");
    
    });
  
  $("#upload").click(function(){
    
    alert("Button clicked");
    
    });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="text" id="autofill"/>
  <button id="upload">Click me to show an alert</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @EternalHour I want `//do stuff` to run when I press enter in the text box; right now it is showing the `alert("test")`, when it should not be, as I show in the snippet. Try pressing enter in the text box. It will show "Button Clicked" instead of "Enter pressed"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to prevent the form from submitting with a `<button>`, you need to specify `type="button"`.

```
<button id="upload" type="button">Click me to show an alert</button>
```

If you do not specify the `type`, the default is `type="submit"`, which will submit the form when you press enter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have strong reason for using the button type 'submit', then try this solution. Catch the 'keypress' event of the textbox and suppress it

```js
$(function() {

  // handle the 'keypress' event to prevent the form submission
  $('#autofill').keypress(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

  });

  $("#autofill").keyup(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13)
      alert("Enter pressed");

  });

  $("#upload").click(function() {

    alert("Button clicked");

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="f">
  <input type="text" id="autofill" />
  <button id="upload">Click me to show an alert</button>
</form>
```